# Print statements unique to each thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm wondering if I can print some stuff that is unique to each thread, so like a number in each print statement to tell which thread it is coming form. Here is my thread implementation:

```
import requests
import time
import threading
import json
from classes.logger import Logger
from classes.cart import Cart
from classes.captcha import Captcha
from classes.queue import Queue
from classes.tools import Tools



if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = requests.Session()
    lock = threading.Lock()
    tools = Tools()
    config = tools.load('config/config.json')
    log = Logger().log
    q = Queue()
    cart = Cart(session, lock)

    api_key = config['key']['2captcha']
    captcha = Captcha(api_key)
    queue = Queue()

    # Small, Medium, Large, one size
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=cart.add_to_cart, args=(['carabiner','palace','silver'],'one size'))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=cart.add_to_cart, args=(['t-shirt','palace','bong'],'small'))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

    cart.check_cart()
```

add_to_cart method:

```
class Cart:

    def add_to_cart(self,keywords,size):
        print("blah blah blah")
```

Would it be possible to print something like:

```
"1 - blah blah blah"
"2 - blah blah blah"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways that I can think of, 1:
You can simply pass an ID argument to your threads, like so

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=cart.add_to_cart, args=(['carabiner','palace','silver'],'one size', '1'))


class Cart:

  def add_to_cart(self,keywords,size, id):
      print(id + "- blah blah blah")
```

Or 2, use the [thread.get_ident()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_ident) value if you plan on starting many threads and don't want to ID them all.

```
class Cart:

  def add_to_cart(self,keywords,size):
      print(threading.get_ident() + "- blah blah blah")
```

Comment: You've a slight typo there: indent -> ident.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks! Just so used to typing indent. To expand to this, you can also look into overloading the print() function, so that you don't have to always include the id in the string. You can either overload, or simply create your own print function.